# What does a "None" mean after compilation of keras model?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, text-classification

I'm trying to implement a binary text classification model using keras layers. After compiling a model, in a summary, I am getting **None** at the bottom end and I don't exactly understand what does it mean?

here is the code which I am using.

```
max_words = 10000
max_len = 500
tok = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tok.fit_on_texts(X_train)
sequences = tok.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
sequences_matrix = sequence.pad_sequences(sequences,maxlen=max_len)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 50, input_length=max_len))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dense(256,name='FC1',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics= 
             ['acc'])
print(model.summary())
```

This is the model summary and at the bottom end It is showing **None**.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 500, 50)           500000    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 64)                29440     
_________________________________________________________________
FC1 (Dense)                  (None, 256)               16640     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 546,337
Trainable params: 546,337
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: It means... `None`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`model.summary()` returns nothing (`None`), and you are printing the return value of it. `model.summary()` already does the printing internally, there is no need to get confused with printing it manually, so just do:

```
model.summary()
```